# How to detect when a chain of actions is done

Tags: angular, ngxs

For example, I dispatch an action. This action dispatches some other action and this is a kind of chain of actions. Depends on the input the chain of actions may be different. When I dispatch an action I do not know the last action so I can not subscribe to concrete action on its success.
So my question is how can I get information that all actions are done?

actions:

```
export class ActionOne {
    static readonly type = 'Action one';
    constructor(public payload: boolean) { }
}

export class ActionTwo {
    static readonly type = 'Action two';
    constructor(public payload: boolean) { }
}

export class ActionThree{
    static readonly type = 'Action three';
    constructor(public payload: boolean) { }
}
```

state:

```
@Action(ActionOne)
actionOne(ctx: StateContext<StateModel>, action: ActionOne): void {
     ctx.dispatch(new ActionTwo());
}

@Action(ActionTwo)
actionTwo(ctx: StateContext<StateModel>, action: ActionTwo): void {
     if(payload) ctx.dispatch(new ActionThree()); else ctx.setState....
}

@Action(ActionThree)
actionThree(ctx: StateContext<StateModel>, action: ActionThree): void {
     ctx.setState....
}
```

action one dispatch

```
this.store.dispatch(new ActionOne(true)) // I don't know a path and last action, but I want to know when it is finished
this.store.dispatch(new ActionOne(false)) // I don't know a path and last action, but I want to know when it is finished
```

actions can be async!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can accomplish this by using the `action` stream to track when your chain has been completed.

First off we need to be sure that the actions life cycle is bound and for this, we need to adjust a bit the code from your second snippet to:

```js
@Action(ActionOne)
actionOne(ctx: StateContext<StateModel>, action: ActionOne): void {
     return ctx.dispatch(new ActionTwo()); // return dispatch here
}

@Action(ActionTwo)
actionTwo(ctx: StateContext<StateModel>, action: ActionTwo): void {
     if(payload) 
       return ctx.dispatch(new ActionThree()); // return the dispatch here
     else ctx.setState
}

@Action(ActionThree)
actionThree(ctx: StateContext<StateModel>, action: ActionThree): void {
     ctx.setState....
}
```

Notice that by returning the dispatch observable in your action handler you'll be binding the action life cycle properly. Meaning that the `ActionOne` will be only complete once the `ActionTwo` is completed.

Now you can watch for the completion of your actions using the `action` stream provided by NGXS. Like the snippet shown below:

```js
import { Actions, ofActionCompleted } from '@ngxs/store'

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(private action$: Actions) {
    this.action$.pipe(
      ofActionCompleted(ActionOne)  // filter the action you desire
      tap((x) => /* DO SOMETHING ABOUT IT */)
    )
  }
}
```

For the value `x` inside the tap you'll receive a object of type `ActionCompletion<T>` where `T` is the action type, in this case `ActionOne`. This interface can be seem ion the snippet below:

```js
interface ActionCompletion<T = any> {
  action: T;
  result: {
    successful: boolean;
    canceled: boolean;
    error?: Error;
  };
}
```